# Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client service can not start with error 1053

Tags: networking, vpn

I am using latest "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client" 4.2.04018. The installation was successful last month when I first install it and it is functional.

Yesterday, I find I cannot start the vpn and find its service "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Service (vpnagent)" is not running. I try to manually start service, but gets an error 1053: the server does not respond to start or control request in a timely fashion.

I uninstall it completely and restart, and then re-install the vpn. The setup gets stuck when starting the service as well. I still could not figure out what is happening after google through the internet.

Comment: The latest from Cisco is 4.5, ask your admins to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this, you need to disable your Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) service to get the Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client service to start.  I completely disabled ICS.  This is what worked for me anyway.